# How can I solve the 100% disk usage issue in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I just want to know how I can solve the disk usage issue that i encounter while using windows 8?

Comment: Have you tried using Resource Monitor to pinpoint which process causes that load? Depending on the programs you've got installed, it could be pretty much anything.

Comment: Are you on the latest Windows Updates?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/830372/hard-drive-windows-8-pro-100-disk-usage-whenever-running-any-program#comment1090463_830372

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Task Bar -> Start Task Manager -> Performance Tab -> Resource Monitor  -> Disk Tab ->  Sort by Total (B/sec) (if missing add this column)